# combine the array inside object using the spread operator

Tags: ecmascript-6

```
let color = ["blue", "red", "yellow" , "green"]

let dataAdditionalBook= {
   Author: "John Doe",
   PublishYear: 2020
}

let book = {
   Name: "basic programming",
   NumberOfPages: 172,
   CoverColor:["black"]
}
// the above code should not be changed or deleted at all

/* Write the answer code here */
```

combine the color variable (combine with the CoverColor attribute) and the dataAdditionalBook into the book variable using the spread operator

Comment: thanks for the reply, its returned to update book object , like this
 Covercolor: [ 'black', 'blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green' ],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to store updated values in `book` object here you go:

```js
let color = ["blue", "red", "yellow", "green"];

let dataAdditionalBook = {
  Author: "John Doe",
  PublishYear: 2020,
};

let book = {
  Name: "basic programming",
  NumberOfPages: 172,
  CoverColor: ["black"],
};

book.CoverColor = [...book.CoverColor, ...color];

book = Object.assign(book, dataAdditionalBook);

console.log(book);
```

Answer (score 0):

first you can combine book CoverColor with with the color

```
const bookWithNewColor = {...book,CoverColor:[...book.CoverColor,...color]} //updated code here
```

after that combine **bookWithNewcolor** and **dataAdditionalBook**

```
const newBook = {...bookWithNewColor,...dataAdditionalBook}

console.log(newBook)
```

the result:

```
{
  name: 'basic programming',
  NumberofPages: 172,
  CoverColor: [ 'black','blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green' ],
  Author: 'John Doe',
  Publish_year: 2020
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what I want is that the black color is still there, not overwritten

Comment: oh yeah, i think i forgot to add spread operator on the book cover color from the original book object. but you can refer the last answer, 
here is the correct code.
const bookWithNewColor = {...book,CoverColor:[...book.CoverColor,...color]}